# Python, Selenium, Firefox: Force PDF Download

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Example: https://apps1.lavote.net/camp/comm.cfm?&cid=82

With Selenium, I am clicking the first Form 497. In my browser, a new tab of the pdf opens. In selenium, nothing seems to happen.

Here is my code, with some parts redacted.

```
def scrape(session_key=None):

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.join(base_dir, 'reports'))
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','application/zip,application/octet-stream,application/x-zip-compressed,multipart/x-zip,application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/rtf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/xls,application/msword,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12,text/plain,text/csv/xls/xlsb,application/csv,application/download,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,application/octet-stream')

    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
    profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/pdf")

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)

    driver.get(magic_url)

    committee_table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table')[2]
    links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in committee_table.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
    
    driver.get('https://apps1.lavote.net/camp/comm.cfm?&cid=82')
    forms_table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('table')[1]
    forms_table_trs = forms_table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')
    for i, row in enumerate(forms_table_trs):
        if i > 0:
            cells = row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')
            print(1)
            try:
                link = cells[2].find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[0]
                
                link.click()
                pdfs = glob.glob(os.path.join(base_dir, 'scraper/*.pdf'))
                latest_pdf_file = max(pdfs, key=os.path.getctime)
                
                parse_funcs[form_type](latest_pdf_file)
                
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

As you may have guessed, there are no pdfs. They are not downloaded. That's why I'm here. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the files and not to test the actual browser dialogue routine, grab the files using Python instead of asking Selenium to do that.

Grab the PDF URLs from the page, then use request to download the file to your memory and then open().write() to save it to the file system.

```
req = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

You can also get the filename from r, but it's a bit bothersome. Check it here: https://www.codementor.io/@aviaryan/downloading-files-from-urls-in-python-77q3bs0un